# If $\frac{k-p^2}{q+r}+\frac{k-q^2}{p+r}+\frac{k-r^2}{p+q} = 4 (p+q+r)$ then find the value of $k$ in terms of $p, q, r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\frac{k-p^2}{q+r}+\frac{k-q^2}{p+r}+\frac{k-r^2}{p+q} = 4 (p+q+r)$ then find the value of $k$ in terms of $p, q, r$

---

One way is to multiply both sides by $(p+q)(q+r)(r+p)$ then proceed on with a gruesome simplifying task. This also accounts for my work as after all that tedious exercise I was left with $k=(p+q+r)^2$

---

However,  I was wondering if there was any other way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $s = p+q+r$ and notice that you want to prove:
$$k\sum\limits_{p,q,r}\dfrac{1}{s-p} = 4s + \sum\limits_{p,q,r}\dfrac{p^2}{s-p}.$$
But since $4s = (s+p)+(s+q)+(s+r),$ the RHS is:
$$4s + \sum\limits_{p,q,r}\dfrac{p^2}{s-p} = \sum\limits_{p,q,r}\left(\dfrac{p^2}{s-p}+(s+p)\right) = \sum\limits_{p,q,r}\dfrac{s^2}{s-p}$$
and you get $k=s^2.$ There is a minor issue of not dividing by zero there but you can take care of that.

Comment: Sir, may you please explain your sigma notations? I found this on [wikipedia][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation] like that pqr thing is nested sum? Or as per my sense and your intention it correctly rpresents plugging in p q r all in place of p on further iterations

Comment: it's just a shorthand and a slight abuse of notation.
$$\sum\limits_{p,q,r} f(p) = f(p) + f(q) + f(r).$$
More formally, one should write the sum $f(a) + f(b) +\ldots + f(z)$ where $a,b,\ldots z$ are all the elements of a set $S$ as:
$$\sum_{s\in S}f(s)$$

Comment: Ohhh goood. I was just worried about that wikipedia's explanation that $\sum\limits_{p,q,r} = \sum\limits_{p}\sum\limits_{q}\sum\limits_{r}$